# Text is distorted in fresh Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, graphics

I've just completed a fresh first install of Ubuntu 64-bit 12.10 and very regularly the on-screen text is distorted.

[image]

How could I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the video driver. Which GPU are you using?

Comment: 01:00.0 "VGA compatible controller" "NVIDIA Corporation" "GF114 [GeForce GTX 555]" -ra1 "NVIDIA Corporation" "Device 0958"
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidiafb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues with the pre-installed drivers are rather common in Ubuntu 12.10.

I haven't tested them myself (because I don't have an nVidia card), but the drivers from [X Updates](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) seem to solve those issues for a lot of people.

You can install the drivers by executing the following commands from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```